# xml DOM : delete element with condition

Tags: php, xml

May be the question is already answered in a way or in another in many questions, but since I'm a new bie in XML, I can't figured it out in my project.

I have an RSS (XML) file with this structure:

```
<rss>
    <channel>
          <item>
                <title>some title</title>
                <description> some descrp </description>
                ...
          </item>
     </channel>
</rss>
```

How can I, in PHP, delete some item when the title is equal to some value? THanks.

EDIT1 : I have my XML file stored at my web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rss = "
<rss>
    <channel>
          <item>
                <title>some title</title>
                <description> some descrp </description>
          </item>
          <item>
                <title>some other title</title>
                <description> some descrp </description>
          </item>
     </channel>
</rss>
";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($rss);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$els = $xpath->query('//title[text()="some title"]');
foreach($els as $el)
{
    $parent = $el->parentNode;
    $parent->parentNode->removeChild($parent);
}
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

It searches for exact match.

ps: another method, without xpath

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($rss);
$els = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
for($i = $els->length-1; $i >= 0; $i--)
{
    $el = $els->item($i);
    if ($el->nodeValue == 'some title')
    {
        $parent = $el->parentNode;
        $parent->parentNode->removeChild($parent);
    }
}
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I would like to import my XML file, it's more bigger than I wrote, it was just to show it's structure. I tried $doc->loadXML("new2.xml"); but it seems not working?

Comment: @hafedh: You have to use `$doc->load("new2.xml")`.

Comment: @Saxoier: THanks a lot, it works, but as it not saving in the file, the new 'data' is displayed on my php page but the XML file still have all items?